# The gradient of the standard mollifier

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, regularization

Please check my proof for the following result:

I want to prove a result for $D\eta_{\epsilon}$ the gradient of the standard mollifier $\eta$. The function $\eta$ is defined as follows:

Let $\eta_{\epsilon}(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ where $\eta(x) = Ce^{\frac{1}{|x|^{2}-1}}$ if $|x|<1$ and $0$ if $|x| \geq 1$.

We know that $\eta(x)$ is smooth and bounded with compact support $\text{spt}(\eta_{\epsilon}) \subset B(0,\epsilon) \subset U$ where $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$, obtaining its maximum at 0.

I want to show what $D\eta_{\epsilon}(x)$ is and conclude that $D\eta_{\epsilon} \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Where $D$ is the gradient vector. To use the chain rule I will let $g_{i}(x_{i}) = \frac{x_{i}}{\epsilon}$ and then by the chain rule we have $\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x_{i}} = \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial g_{i}}\frac{\partial g_{i}}{\partial x_{i}}$.

$D\eta_{\epsilon}(x) := D(\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}} \eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon}))$ $= \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}D(\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon}))$ =$\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}(\frac{\partial \eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})}{\partial x_{i}}, ...,\frac{\partial \eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})}{\partial x_{n}})$ = $\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n}}(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial g_{i}}, ...,\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial g_{n}})$ = $\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n+1}}(\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial g_{i}}, ...,\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial g_{n}})$

Since $\eta$ is bounded with compact support it follows that each $\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial g_{i}}$ will be bounded on compact supports and therefore $|D \eta_{\epsilon}| < \infty$ and $D \eta_{\epsilon} \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.

Is this proof fine? Thanks for assistance.

Comment: Being bounded and compactly supported does not imply finite derivatives. Why not just calculate $\eta'(x)$ and show it's bounded for $|x|<1$?

Comment: @p.s. If we already know that $\eta$ is smooth (which is the case), then $\eta$ being compactly supported implies that $D\eta $ is bounded (because it's continuous with compact support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need the computation of $D\eta_\epsilon$. The gradient of any smooth compactly supported function is bounded, being itself a continuous function with compact support. Since $\eta$ is smooth and has compact support, the rescaled function $\eta_\epsilon$ also has those properties.  The conclusion follows.

Comment: Yes I agree with what you are saying, I didn't specify this but this is only one component of a larger problem where I am required to show that I can get the $(\frac{1}{\epsilon^{n+1}})$ factor out. So I just wanted to know if the computation was sound.